# EntityFrameworkCore - It is possible to configure a unique database for each user?

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-core

My client asked to build an API in ASP NET Core for a business management application. Nonetheless, he made me an unusual requirement for me: He needs each user to have their own database. All databases have the same structure of tables and relationships and all are MySql.

This means that each user will need their own connection string and some way to store that information.

In addition, other users will be added in the future, each with a bank created just for their use.

Anyway, I don't know if this is possible, but if it is, how would I do it?

Comment: It's possible, but you'll have many issues, make sure what exactly need (not want) you client.

Comment: Instead you should add "owner" column to each table which needs to be owned... And then filter records based on logged user... Making new database looks like a terrible idea

Comment: @Selvin yes, this is much better than his idea. The problem is that the entire database structure is already set up. I'll see with him a viable solution.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's "already set up". Tear it down and redo it better. Your client is not a systems architect. Implementation details are not their domain.

Comment: @madreflection Well, I think I forgot to give some details. First, he's a systems architect, but not a web architect. Second, other company systems that are out of my access depend on this already implemented database structure. So I can't redo but anyway, I'll try to negotiate another solution with him. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: Not a very good systems architect, I'm afraid. A database per user doesn't scale. It's a maintence nightmare. Schema changes have to be applied to each database, and that's just the start of it. He obviously doesn't know the impact of such a poor decision.

Comment: @madreflection I'm also afraid of it, as you said a poor decision.

Comment: So reject the requirement and do it better, for everyone's sake.